# How to make a PATCH request with jSONObjectRequest in android volley?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-volley, androidhttpclient

I want to make a PATCH request with json object request in android using volley library.
Its working in postman but when i call it in android, it gives me error 405,Anybody have any idea How to do it? Below is my code:

```
requestQueue.add( new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.PATCH,url, jsonObject, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                        GiveCentralUtilities.setCurrentFragment(getActivity(),R.id.fragment_container,
                                SignUpPaymentInfo.newInstance(isSignup),SignUpPaymentInfo.TAG);


                        //  getAccessToken();

                    }
                }, this){
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String,String> header = new HashMap<String, String>();
                header.put("Authorization","Bearer "+GiveCentralUtilities.getPref(GiveCentralConstants.ACCESSTOKEN,getActivity()));
                header.put("Accept", "application/json");
                //  header.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                System.out.println("vivekaccess"+GiveCentralUtilities.getPref(GiveCentralConstants.ACCESSTOKEN,getActivity()));

                return header;
            }


            @Override
            public String getBodyContentType() {
                return "application/json";
            }

        });
```

Comment: Did you get the answer ?
Or did you tried something else ?

Answer (score 0):

Error 405 means that this error does not come from your JsonObjectRequest. It may be caused by the url, your android phone's network or the server

Comment: ok. Put its working on the postman. Please tell me how to solve it. @Mark Shen

Comment: I have no idea either. The information you provided is not enough to solve the problem.